# ListView with rows containing a LinearLayout

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a list using the ListView, which contains rows built with a LinearLayout. This LinearLayout is composed of a checkbox and a textview. The layout of the row is named tasks_list_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then from my code I initialize the list this way:

```
final String[] items_task = new String[] { "one",
                "two",
                "three" };

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.tasks_list_row, items_task));
```

But then I get an error:
**ArrayAdapter - You must supply a resource ID for a TextView**

I then try to specify the TextView id this way:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.text1, R.layout.tasks_list_row, items_task));
```

But I get a Resource not found error (R.id.text1 exists in the R.java file).

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you need to use android.R.id.text1, as you're referencing the built in android ID (@android:id was the clue).

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.tasks_list_row, android.R.id.text1, items_task));
```

There isn't much advantage to doing this, unless you're using built in layouts, such as android.R.layout.two_line_list_item

Comment: I agree with @David on this.  I see no reason that you should use @android:id/text1 for the id of the text field in your own layout.  If you just use @+id/text1 then your code should work and the ID is in your project space.

Comment: Yes, I think it is easier to follow if you stick to your own identifiers. You can usually use more descriptive names in this case, like title or heading rather than text1.

Comment: I did it, and I got this error: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File from xml type layout resource ID #0x1020014  (that ID doesn't exist in my R.java file)

Comment: Try using android:id="@+id/text1" in your layout XML, and then R.id.text1 as the second parameter to the ArrayAdapter constructor.

Comment: Yes, I tried it before and it throws a similar error: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050004 type #0x12 is not valid

Comment: Try cleaning your project in Eclipse, and check the correct R is imported, if necessary. Sometimes Eclipse messes up the building of a project and you'll need to fiddle to get R built correctly.

Comment: I tried, but it still throws an error. Are you sure that's possible? I tried the CheckedTextView and it works, but I can't get it with the LinearLayout.

Comment: Oops - always check the API! The viewResourceId and layoutResourceId parameters are the wrong way around. I've updated my answer above. See http://j.mp/fgTl3g

Comment: That's correct David, now it works :)  I checked the API but I didn't realize of that... thanks! (I'm giving you 1 reputation vote for your help and effort)

Answer (score 0):

try with the android default textview id; `android.R.id.text1`

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to your LinearLayout android:id="@android:id/tasks_list_row" and use this instead

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.tasks_list_row, items_task));
```

Each item will have the xml that you have specified. You could instead use a CheckedTextView which combines a `TextView` with a `CheckBox`.

Comment: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050004 type #0x12 is not valid