# getting an illegalStateException for listview

Tags: android, listview, illegalstateexception

i have a table layout where i am displaying some data from the database.
i have kept the row of the table layout as clickable as i want to show all the details from the database related to that row in a list view after the user clicks that row.
after clicking m getting an **IllegalStateException**...

```
04-30 11:17:03.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9466): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource        ID to be a TextView
04-30 11:17:03.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9466):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
04-30 11:17:03.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9466):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
04-30 11:17:03.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9466):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
04-30 11:17:03.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9466):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
04-30 11:17:03.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9466):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
04-30 11:17:03.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9466):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
04-30 11:17:03.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9466):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
04-30 11:17:03.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9466):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
04-30 11:17:03.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9466):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
04-30 11:17:03.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9466):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
```

anybody has any idea what the problem is?? please help!

the listview code:

```
settings = getSharedPreferences("LandTshare", MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefEditor = settings.edit();

    rowid=settings.getInt("rowid", 0);

    WayDataBase way=new WayDataBase(getApplicationContext());

    ArrayList<String> listvalues=way.getListDetails(rowid);
    if(listvalues.size()!=0)
    {
        ListView lv=getListView();
        ListAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListViewDetails.this, R.layout.view_animal_entry,listvalues);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

view_animal_entry.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/animalId"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/animalName"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:paddingLeft="6dip"
       android:paddingTop="6dip"
       android:textColor="#A4C739"
       android:textSize="17sp"
       android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: plz post some code...

Comment: @ling.s i have posted the code for list view and adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change your line from

```
ListAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListViewDetails.this, R.layout.view_animal_entry,listvalues);
```

**To This**

```
  ListAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListViewDetails.this, R.layout.view_animal_entry, R.id.animalName, listvalues);
```

This should work. You have to specifi a `textview id` to show data.

Comment: now m getting resource not found exception after putting the line `ListAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListViewDetails.this, android.R.id.text1, R.layout.view_animal_entry,listvalues);`

Comment: Please read the answer again. 
Provide the textview id at the place of android.R.id.text1 which you defined in your layout R.layout.view_animal_entry

Comment: oops sorry my bad! but even after putting the id as R.id.animalName(you can the xml file in my edited post) it still is showing resource not found exception... `04-30 12:20:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(29307): 
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
Resource ID #0x7f0a0154 type #0x12 is not valid
`

Comment: Sorry this its my mistake. Just swap  R.id.animalName and R.layout.view_animal_entry with each other.
I have updated my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

In the `ArrayAdapter` constructor, the textViewResourceId must refer to a TextView resource ID.

Can you show us your code, and ensure that it's the case ?

Taken from the javadoc :

> By default this class expects that the provided resource id references a single TextView.
>        If you want to use a more complex layout, use the constructors that also takes a field
>        id. That field id should reference a TextView in the larger layout resource.

**Edit :** you second issue is a possible duplicate of [ListView with rows containing a LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462356/listview-with-rows-containing-a-linearlayout)

It seems that you may avoid this `Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0a0154 type #0x12 is not valid` message by using the default id :

in your layout XML :

```
<TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"/>
```

and in your code :

```
ListAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListViewDetails.this, android.R.id.text1, R.layout.view_animal_entry,listvalues);
```

(I'm not sure why a given ID does not work in that case)

Comment: now m getting resource not found exception after putting the line `ListAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListViewDetails.this, android.R.id.text1, R.layout.view_animal_entry,listvalues);`

Comment: Try changing `android.R.id.text1` to `R.id.animalName`

Comment: yes i did that...but even after putting the id as R.id.animalName(you can the xml file in my edited post) it still is showing resource not found exception... 04-30 12:20:51.362: E/AndroidRuntime(29307): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0a0154 type #0x12 is not valid

Comment: Please, show the full stacktrace (or at least the 3-4 first lines)

Comment: `04-30 12:40:25.882: E/AndroidRuntime(30976): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0a0154 type #0x12 is not valid
04-30 12:40:25.882: E/AndroidRuntime(30976):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2144)
04-30 12:40:25.882: E/AndroidRuntime(30976):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:853)
04-30 12:40:25.882: E/AndroidRuntime(30976):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
`